# Powershell script for Backup cleanup does not work in windows server 2016

Tags: powershell, backup, delete-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have been working on a PowerShell script that deletes backup folders and leaves only the latest 3 backup folders. I have test run the script on a schedule using task scheduler and it works.
But, when I implement it on the machine with windows server 2016, it runs and prompts the completion of the script but it doesn't delete the folders. I know the script has been executed because I attached an email notification details in the script. I receive the email prompting the completion of the task but, the deletion does not take place.

I am attaching the script that I am using below, hope I can get some help on this issue.

```
  # Gets path of Backup folder
$backup_path = 'C:\Backup'

  # Getting the subfolders inside the Backup folder
$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $backup_path -Directory -Force

  # Checks if the number of folders is more than 3**
if ($subfolders.Count -gt 3) {

    # Sort subfolders by Creation Time
    $sorted_subfolders = $subfolders | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime

    # Getting number of subfolders to delete
    $delete_count = $subfolders.Count - 3

    # Deletes the subfolders and their contents
    $sorted_subfolders[0..($delete_count - 1)] | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Write a message to the console when deletion complete 
    Write-Output "Deleted $($delete_count) subfolders"

    # Create a string for email with the folder names
    $email_body = "The Backup Management Script Has been Executed Successfully!`n`n" +
                  "The following folders were deleted from the SQL backup folder:`n" +
                  ($sorted_subfolders[0..($delete_count - 1)].Name -join "`n") + "`n`n" +
                  "The following folders are left in the SQL backup folder:`n" +
                  ($sorted_subfolders[$delete_count..($subfolders.Count - 1)].Name -join "`n")

}
else {
    # Writes email to Admin when Latest 3 Backup folders are left**

    $email_body = "No backup Folder Older than 3 Days Have been Found!`n Please Check If the Backup has run as scheduled."
}

   # Sends email notification
    $SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient
    $MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
    $SmtpClient.Host = "SMTP server IP"
    $mailmessage.from = ("Noreply.backup@domain.com")
    $mailmessage.To.add("Admin@domain.com")
    $mailmessage.Subject = "Backup Cleanup Job"
    $mailmessage.Body = $email_body
    $smtpclient.Send($mailmessage)
```

I tried Changing Execution Policy to RemoteSigned but, It still didn't delete the folder.
The backup folder was in located in a shared folder so I moved it out to local folder on the server. The script can detect the folder and extract names of the folder but, it doesn't seem to be able to delete those folders.

Answer (score 0):

So, The above Post was not complete. I have run the script on my PC and it runs and Deletes the subfolders as it should but, it doesn't work on the server (Windows Server 2016). As suggested by Max I added the Write-Warning $error[0] to the script.
The Error Said the script was not digitally signed. So, I set the Execution policy to bypass. It doesn't save that configuration and says,

" WARNING: Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more sp
ecific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-Execution
Policy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy". "